# ¿Cómo eliminar un registro utilizando SweetAlert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert2

Cuando presiono el botón eliminar hago que me aparezca la alerta con el mensaje de eliminar, y luego al momento de presionar el botón de eliminar, el registro NO se elimina. El problema viene a ser que al momento de presionar el botón de eliminar el método AJAX no se ejecuta.

**Eventos**

```
<script>
//Aquí hago que aparezca la alerta acompañado del valor del "id". 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-eliminar").on("click", function () {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Está seguro que desea eliminar esta Charla?',
            text: "No podrá recuperar los datos!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCloseButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminarlo!',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            html: `<div class="lbl-id-oculto">${$(this).parent().siblings(".td-id").text().trim()}</div>`
        })
    });

    //Aquí esta el código de la acción eliminar, cuando presiono eliminar le envió el parametro "id" para que sepa que registro eliminar, pero NO ELIMINA NADA.
    $(document).on("click", ".swal2-confirm", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("EliminarCharla", "Charlas")',
            data: { id: $(this).parent().siblings(".swal2-content").find(".lbl-id-oculto").text().trim() },
            success: function (rpta) {

            },
            error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Controlador**

```
        public ActionResult EliminarCharla(string id) 
        {
         ClsConexion con = new ClsConexion();
         var Cnx = con.Conexion();

         OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SIMEXA_SP_ELIMINAR_CHARLA", Cnx);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = id;
         Cnx.Open();

         OracleTransaction tx = Cnx.BeginTransaction();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         tx.Commit();

         Cnx.Close();
         cmd.Dispose();
         Cnx.Dispose();

         return RedirectToAction("MostraCharlas");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como tal `SweetAlert` tiene su forma de validar la opción seleccionada, esto se realiza a través de un `then`.

```
$(".btn-eliminar").on("click", function () {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Está seguro que desea eliminar esta Charla?',
        text: "No podrá recuperar los datos!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCloseButton: true,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminarlo!',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        html: `<div class="lbl-id-oculto">${$(this).parent().siblings(".td-id").text().trim()}</div>`
    }).then((choice) => {
        if (choice.value === true) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("EliminarCharla", "Charlas")',
                data: { id: $(this).parent().siblings(".swal2-content").find(".lbl-id-oculto").text().trim() },
                success: function (rpta) {

                },
                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.